# how to pass value of variable to pipeline in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a variable

```
THING="echo '3'; echo '5'; echo '4'; echo '3';"
```

and I want to shove it into a pipeline like:

```
THING2=$( { $THING } | /peep.exe )
```

how do I do that? When I try the top one it gives me some errors, but when I try it as:

```
THING2=$( { echo '3'; echo '5'; echo '4'; echo '3'; } | ./peep.exe )
```

it works fine.

Comment: trouble is that your 1st `echo` is treating the rest of the line `'3'; echo '5'; echo '4'; echo '3';"` as its arguments and so not letting the shell interpret them as subsequent commands.

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use variables for code; use functions.

```
thing () {
    echo '3'
    echo '5'
    echo '4'
    echo '3'
}

thing2=$( thing | /peep.exe )
```

Comment: IMO, it is harmful, because it validates an unnecessary approach. People see one use of `eval`, don't understand *why* it is OK in that situation, and try to apply it in an unsafe situation. It's best to leave `eval` alone until you *really* need it (which for most people is "never").

Comment: (The preceding was in response to a now-deleted comment asking about using `eval` in this situation.)

Comment: What if I want to generate lots and lots  of echo's with numbers? Like make a loop that generates 1000s of echo's from 0 to 1000 ? How could I stick that into the function? 

Basically, I'm trying to pipeline 1000s of echo commands.

Comment: @Dmytro Rather than trying to "pipeline thousands of echo commands", it seems like you are merely trying to generate thousands of lines of output.  Rather than a string of echos, you could use a single command that generates the output.  (eg, `printf "3\n5\n4\n3\n"` or `echo 3; seq 5 3` or `cat  datafile` or `cat << EOF ...` or some other more reasonable way of generating the desired output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the peep.exe accepts an array, the first echo is the size of the array, the rest of the echos are the values of the array. I need to feed it an array of a large size. I don't need the output of it, I need it to run and measure the time it takes to process the array I give it.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question describing your exact use case. Generally, if you have a shell array with thousands of elements, there is probably a better approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are intending to do is to pass the literal string "echo '3'...." etc to the next app in the pipeline, then this code will suffice.

If you are intending to pass only 3,5,4,3 numbers, then @Chepner reply will do.

Hope this is good for you.

```
THING="echo '3'; echo '5'; echo '4'; echo '3';"
echo "$THING"

THING2=$( echo "$THING" | grep "3" )
echo  "$THING2"
```